# Minimum set to cover all patterns within Hamming distance 1

Tags: python, combinations

You have 2 kinds of letters {A,B}.

The length of string is 3.

Then num of all patterns are 8:
AAA, AAB, ABA, ABB, BAA, BAB, BBA, BBB

Now I'd like to pick up some of them to cover all the patterns within 1 Hamming distance.

ex1)

set(AAA, BBB) satisfies this.

AAA, AAB, ABA, BAA is 0 or 1 hamming distance to AAA

ABB, BAB, BBA, BBB is 0 or 1 hamming distance to BBB

so all the patterns are covered by set(AAA, BBB)

ex2)

set(AAA, AAB) dose not satisfies this.

AAA, AAB, ABA, BAA is 0 or 1 hamming distance to AAA

ABB, BAB, is 0 or 1 hamming distance to AAB

BBA, BBB is 2 hamming distance to AAA or AAB

so they are not covered by set(AAA, AAB)

If the letters are 3 types: {A, B, C}

The length are 10. AAAAAAAAAA, AAAAAAAAAB, ..., CCCCCCCCCC

How to get a combinations to cover all the patterns within 1 hamming distance?

```
from itertools import product, combinations

all_patterns = set(product('ABC', repeat=10))

def hamming(patterns1, patterns2):
    for pattern2 in patterns2:
        if min(sum(a!=b for a, b in zip(pattern1, pattern2)) for pattern1 in patterns1) > 1:
            return False
    return True

def calc_minimum_patterns():
    for i in range(1, len(all_patterns)):
        for patterns in combinations(all_patterns, i):
            if hamming(patterns, all_patterns):
                return patterns
```

Comment: I'm using python.
product and combinations from itertools module were used to solve the problem.
But it took too much time to calculate all the combinations.

Any idea to slove this?

Comment: I'm sure this code will generate the patterns I want.
However, it actually doesn't finish in time since order is too big.